# C struct error "pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed"

Tags: c, linux, pointers, struct

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Professional and I've tried it in Eclipse on Kali and Ubuntu as well.

There are more areas where the same two errors occur, though I will only show some of the code here.

I've seen a few questions related to the same problem.  Most of the answers seemed to be that the struct was not previously defined though I don't think that applies here.  I have also tried to putting all the code into a single source file, this changed nothing.

Visual Studio underlines the errors in code showing `error: pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed` and when I build the project it shows `error C2037: left of 'previous' specifies undefined struct/union 'NODE'` These locations are noted in the code below.

Another error is `warning C4133: '=' : incompatible types - from 'NODE *' to 'NODE *'` and the locations are noted below as well.

So of course my question is how do I fix these errors?

The relevant information from my header file:

```
list.h
    #ifndef LIST_H
    #define LIST_H

    typedef struct node{
        struct NODE *next;
        struct NODE *previous;
    }NODE;

    typedef struct list{
        NODE node;
        int count;
    }LIST;

    extern void     listDelete(LIST *pList, NODE *pNode);
    extern void     listFree(LIST *pList);
    #endif
```

The relevant information from my C source file:

```
list.c
    #include "list.h"
    #define HEAD    node.next       /* first node in list */  
    #define TAIL    node.previous       /* last node in list */  

    void listDelete(LIST *pList, NODE *pNode)
    {
        NODE *mynode;
        if (pNode->previous == NULL)
        {
            pList->HEAD = pNode->next;
        }
        else
        {
            pNode->previous->next = pNode->next; // pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed
        }

        if (pNode->next == NULL)
        {
            pList->TAIL = pNode->previous;
        }
        else
        {
            pNode->next->previous = pNode->previous; // pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed
        }

        pList->count--;
    }

    void listFree(LIST *pList)
    {
        NODE *p1, *p2;

        if (pList->count > 0)
        {
            p1 = pList->HEAD; // warning C4133: '=' : incompatible types - from 'NODE *' to 'NODE *'
            while (p1 != NULL)
            {
                p2 = p1->next; // warning C4133: '=' : incompatible types - from 'NODE *' to 'NODE *'
                free((char *)p1);
                p1 = p2;
            }
            pList->count = 0;
            pList->HEAD = pList->TAIL = NULL;
        }
    }
```

Comment: note: If you use typedef struct struct-name {} typedef-name,  typedef-name will be in the global namespace. `struct NODE id` is not a valid statement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't use `NODE` inside the definition of `struct node`, because `NODE` isn't defined yet.

The slow way to do it would be:

```
struct node {
    struct node *next;
    struct node *previous;
};

typedef struct node NODE;
```

so that after you define what `struct node` is, you can refer to it as `NODE`.

---

Change

```
typedef struct node{
    struct NODE *next;
    struct NODE *previous;
}NODE;
```

to

```
typedef struct node {
    struct node *next;
    struct node *previous;
} NODE;
```